# How would I associate the BusyConfig.busy to Observables when a Promise isn't available?

Tags: angular, promise, observable

On the examples, all of the codes are done with simple methods where the busy == promise.

```
onClickTwo() {
  const busy = new Promise<any>((resolve) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      resolve();
    }, 5000);
  });
  this.busyConfigTwo.busy = [busy];
}
```

But in the codebase I am working with, none of the calls are done with promises but are done via an Observable().subscribe(...)

How do I link together a subscribe to this IBusyConfig.busy for ngBusy to operate?

Comment: what example are you following? You can have similar functionality with just using plain rxjs

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xk9cw5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can always convert a promise to observable and vice-versa. To convert a Observable to promise all you need to do is call `toPromise` method on Observable. e.g

```
//return basic observable
const sample = val => Rx.Observable.of(val).delay(5000);
//convert basic observable to promise
const example = sample('First Example')
  .toPromise()
  //output: 'First Example'
  .then(result => {
    console.log('From Promise:', result);
  });
```

For more please refer this [link](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/utility/topromise.html)

Moreover, I see `ngBusy` also accepts subscription apart from promise as below . So can do the following also :

```
import {  of } from 'rxjs';
onClickTwo() {
  this.busyConfigTwo.busy = of(['whatever']).subscribe();
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Your post help me move forward and get this code of ours to work in a manner that appears to be correct. In particular the ".busy = ..subscribe()".

Comment: In order to get around minimizing changes to our code I just 'this.subscription = ourObservable.suscribe();' then this.busyConfig.busy = [this.subscription];' Only issue I'm having is the mat-spinner does not spin.